# Trying to make div elements show with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to keep the div elements hidden by default, and when you click the css button it should show div element in the center, I've tried the following code so far but it doesn't display the div elements at all when using "display:none" with .show jquery. I think i'm messing up on the textbutton linking part.

jQuery

```
<div class="social" style="display:none">some text</div>
<script>    
$("s").click(function(){
$("social").show();
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<li id="s"><a href="#s"> <text class="s">Social</a></li></text>
```

The "Social" text is a css button.

EDIT: Fixed now, was a silly mistake, sorry.

Comment: There is no `<s>` element. `$("s").click(function(){`. You probably meant the ID `$("#s").click(function(){` or the class `$(".s").click(function(){`.

Comment: What is `<text>` ? and where is class="social" ?

Comment: Fixed it, silly mistake, I had text class, li id and href all using "s". Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace

```
<script>    
  $("s").click(function(){
    $("social").show();
  });
</script>
```

by

```
<script>    
  $(function() {
    $("#s").click(function(){
      $(".social").show();
    });
  });
</script>
```

`$(function() { ... })` is the same as `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

If you don't wait for the document ready, jquery can't access your s element.

Comment: Tried most of the comments here, none of them seem to be working, adding site link to the main post.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your code inside DOM ready and you're currently missing `#` to target `id` and `.` to target `class`, the code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#s").click(function(){
        $(".social").show();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
$("#s").click(function(){
    $(".social").show();
});
```

You have missed `.` which is class selector and `#` is ID selector.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector are wrong, it should be like CSS : `#` for id's and `.` for classes.

```
$("#s").click(function(){
    $(".social").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with the "#" for the ID and "." for the CLASS

```
$("#s").click(function(){
    $(".social").show();
});
```

Comment: and a dot for the class

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ensure your code will not be executed before the DOM is ready. Thus, wrap it with:

```
$(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Second, you are missing ID and CLASS identifiers in your code:

```
<div class="social" style="display:none">some text</div>
<script>    
    $("#s").click(function(){
        $(".social").show();
    });
</script>
```